# Hive internal table takes block size larger than configured

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

My configuration for `dfs.blocksize` is `128M`, and if I upload any file or create any file, it takes block of size `128M` which is cool. But when I create hive table it , however small may be, takes block size of `256M`.[image: Screenshot of my table in HDFS]
Can we set size of table when they are created? I don't know how it's done

**UPDATE**
I am using spark sql.

```
spark = SparkSession .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://bigdata-
                 namenode:9000/user/hive/warehouse")
                .config("mapred.input.dir.recursive", true)
                .config("hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories", true)
                .config("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", true)
                .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
                //.master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
String query1 = String.format("INSERT INTO TABLE bm_top."+orc_table+" SELECT  icode, store_code,division,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(bill_date,'dd-MMM-yy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'), qty, bill_no, mrp FROM bm_top.temp_ext_table");
 spark.sql(query1);
```

Comment: How do you create table (provide create table statement) ? And how do you load data ?

Comment: I have updated my question